# Save multiple value in the multiple database with one button codeigniter mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I am just new in CodeIgniter and still learning and exploring it.
I have this view where the user adds category and sizes. It has the unlimited or dynamic input field in sizes, so if the category for ex. Pants, pants have many sizes so the user will just click the add more button. But here's the thing I am stocked in saving all the inputs.  I want to save the category and the corresponding size of the category.
Here's my table

```
    CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `sizes` (
  `size_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `size` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`size_id`),
         KEY `cat_fk_idx` (`category_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `cat_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` 
        (`category_id`) 
             )
```

And here's my view.php

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('errorMessage');?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('successMessage');?>
<?php echo form_open('category_con/add_category'); ?>
<?php echo form_fieldset('<h1 class="text-danger">Categories</h1>'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for='Username'>Add New Category</label>
    <input type="text" name="category_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Add new Category here">
</div>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>         
                <div class="form-group">  
                     <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                          <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                    <tr>  
                                         <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Add Size" class="form-control name_list" /></td>  
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                    </tr>  
                               </table>  

                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="save_category" class="btn btn-success" value="Save Category">
</div>           
</div>  

 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Add Size" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"name.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

I hope you would help me. Thanks.

Comment: you  forgot your controller code

Comment: my controller is still in trial and error. So hope you would help in the cotroller and model part. Thanks

Comment: So you want us to code 2/3 of *your* work?

Comment: Do you want to save data in multiple database or multiple tables ?

Comment: @Rajeevbbqq multiple tables

Answer (score 1):

Create a model with name **Test.php**

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Model
{

    public function create()
    {
        $data = array(
           array(
              'category_name' => 'Data Input of category_name' // data input (category_name)
           ),
           array(
              'category_name' => 'Data Input category_name'   // data input (category_name)
           )
        );


        $this->db->insert_batch('category', $data); 

        $last_row_id = $this->db->insert_id();  // Gets last row id ( category_id )

        $data = array(
           array(
                'size'        => 'Data input of size' ,
                'category_id' => $last_row_id
           ),
           array(
                'size'        => 'Data input of size' ,
                'category_id' => $last_row_id
           )
        );


        $this->db->insert_batch('sizes', $data);

    }


}
```

***You can pass as much as data dynamically into model class***

In somewhere on your controller

```
$this->load->model('test'); //Model loaded
$this->test->create();     // Insertion happened to multiple tables
```

Comment: i just want to ask if, does this save the unlimited field or dynamic field?

Comment: I got this error, A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion